# Tennis tournament proof that $n + 1$ players can form a line

Tags: combinatorics, induction

> At a tennis tournament, there were $2^n$ participants, and any two of them played against each other exactly one time. Prove that we can find $n+1$ players that can form a line in which everybody has defeated all the players who are behind him in the line.

How would you prove this by induction? Also what does it mean to form a line? Thanks

Comment: To form a line, we need to find a group of $n+1$ players, one of whom has defeated all the rest.  That one can stand in front.  There must be a second who defeated all the others except the first, who will stand second, and so on.  Try it with small $n$.  If $n=1$, there are $2$ players and you need to find $2$ of them who can stand in line.  Can you?  If $n=2$ there are $4$ players and you need to find $3$.  Can you guarantee that?

Comment: Just in case there's a cultural gap: "A line" of people in some parts of the world is more commonly called "a queue" of people.

Answer (score 2):

On average, everyone wins against $(2^n-1)/2$ players, so some player, $x$, has won against $2^{n-1}$ players. Find a line of $n$ among the players $x$ beat (by induction), then put $x$ at the end of the line.